# Building an angular feature module as an angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am building an angular feature module as an library so that it will allow us to build a module individually without rebuilding the entire angular application. The application seems to be working in this way, however, is it a best practice to do like this and is it aot compiled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library is something you keep out of the actual project (i.e as a library) so that it can be reused in many projects.

If this kind of library is what you are referring to take a look at how to create ng libraries in angular docs.

On the other hand a feature module is something that you load on demand rather than on application startup.
This is acheived through lazy loading and improves application start time.

So i say have a library project outside your normal project and add this module code there. The libraries are aot build and then used.

Comment: yeah, thats true and correct. what we are trying to achive is, we have an enterprise application with close to 100 modules and we want to build them individually. and these modules are dependent on each other as well. So building a module as an library gave us the possibility to build a module individually.

Comment: then 'library' is a misleading term :) it is just a normal angular module and approach is fine. please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: yeah, thing is building an module and library is different and i mentioned it as an library so that it brings more clarity on the approach that i have used for building.